# Как сравнить содержимое двух каталогов на диске и вывести на экран список файлов и подкаталогов, созданных в один день?

Tags: cmd, bat

Дали задачу сравнить содержимое двух каталогов на диске (имя диска указывается в качестве параметра) и вывести на экран список тех файлов и подкаталогов, которые созданные в один день(с помощью BAT - файлов). Думаю над задачей целый день но ничего получается из-за небольшого опыта работы с BAT-файлами, как можно реализовать? Надеюсь надеюсь кто-то поможет)

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, ваши попытки решить задачу

Comment: Рекомендую использовать утилиту **forfiles**, позволяющую обрабатывать (рекурсивно) списки файлов и вызывать команды для обработки файлов. Ею можно (опционально) фильтровать файлы по датам.